# Preference Headers embedded with a Switch button without linking to a fragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preference-headers

I am trying to customize preference headers. few headers should be linked to a fragment and open a new preference screen upon tapping it. few headers should be embedded with a switch and not be linked to any fragment. touch on these headers shouldnt work .  When i tried to create a header with out linking to fragment, It is coming as header title to list of headers. i need a list of headers with switch button and no fragment/new preference screen. Is it possible?? is there a way to disable Onheaderclick for few headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an extra item in the preference xml and  don't define the onclick event for that particular item ...

Comment: Could you please share an example?  what is that extra item? do u mean a header?  could you please elaborate on how to disable onheaderclick for particular Header. That will actually solve my problem